Calculating Jones polynomials for virtual links in mathematica
So, the KnotTheory package for Mathematica is advertised as working for classical links. But one can construct a PD code for a virtual link as well. Will this package correctly calculate the Jones polynomial from it?

I don't know for sure, but I expect the KnotTheory package would compute virtual Jones polynomials correctly. You could check with https://knotfol.io/, which computes virtual Jones polynomials.
